# replace text in TeX

Tags: latex, tex

Is there a way to add a text by reference using LaTeX? I have several text references to 'versionXX.yy'. I wonder if I can define this in one place so I don't need to update it in all places.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a variable or new command with your version at the beginning and then just use this definition. See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35929/using-string-variable-with-latex?rq=1)

Btw. there is a special site called [tex.stackexchange.com](https://tex.stackexchange.com) for this kind of questions.

Comment: ok, this works well. However, I still have a problem:

`code`
\begin{fullwidth}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=bash]
mv ~/Downloads/application_\Version.bin ..     # Move installer to home directory
\end{lstlisting}
\end{fullwidth}
`endcode`

In this case it does not work. I am new to LaTeX :/

P.S.: sorry for the formatting :(

Comment: The listing environment will print everything in the way you write it down. And I'm not sure if you can use variables in there